# TableView Cell Tapped Returning Nil in Segue

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, segue, didselectrowatindexpath

I'm trying to pass table view information to a View Controller and am getting this "fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value".  Here is my code.....

```
  func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath)
    {
        self.resultsTableView.deselectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: true)

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) { () -> Void in
            self.performSegueWithIdentifier("playerSegue", sender: self.resultsTableView)
        }

    }
```

and...

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?)
{
    if segue.identifier == "playerSegue"
    {
        let index = resultsTableView.indexPathForSelectedRow!.row
        let controller = segue.destinationViewController as! VideoViewController
        controller.vidTitleLBL.text = self.videoTitle[index]
        controller.videoId = self.videoId[index]

    }
}
```

It's not showing information at indexPath.row.  Also the cell is a custom UITableViewCell and the videoTitle and videoId is coming from an array of YouTube JSON items.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it by establishing a public int...

```
var selectedVideoIndex: Int!
```

didSelectRowAtIndexPath as.....
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath)
    {

```
    selectedVideoIndex = indexPath.row
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
        self.performSegueWithIdentifier("seguePlayer", sender: self)

    })

}
```

and prepareForSegue as...

```
 override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?)
    {
        if segue.identifier == "seguePlayer"
        {

            print(self.videoTitle[selectedVideoIndex])
            print(self.videoId[selectedVideoIndex])
            let controller = segue.destinationViewController as! VideoViewController
            controller.vidTitleText = self.videoTitle[selectedVideoIndex]
            controller.videoId = self.videoId[selectedVideoIndex]
            controller.vidDescription = self.videoDescription[selectedVideoIndex]
            controller.vidIMG = self.videoIMG[selectedVideoIndex]

        }
    }
```

Also, since my information from YouTube API dictionary was cast out as Strings, I had to establish empty Strings in my VideoViewController and make my label.text(s) equal them there.  If there was a better way to do this please comment below.

Answer (score 2):

You made a harm to yourself by doing `self.resultsTableView.deselectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: true)` before you perform segue.

After you deselect the row, you asynchronously perform a segue.
When `prepareForSegue` method is called, `resultsTableView.indexPathForSelectedRow` is `nil` already, because you deselected previously selected row.

Comment: This is absolutely correct. And from my knowledge, the asynchronous call doesn't necessarily make the value nil, it's the fact that no matter what, the previously selected row is no longer selected.

Comment: OK...that was bad coding I got from somewhere else trying to fix this problem.  I removed it and its still coming up nil....any thoughts? btw..my initial array is ----- var videoTitle = [String]() --- could that be the problem?

Comment: Any swift conventions? By specifying ! you are unwrapping optionals without checks. Implement checks on nil, check where nil is instead of what you expected and rework your code to avoid that.